# How can I check if a few selected elements in one listbox, are divisible by 3 and they are integers?

Tags: c#, listbox, selected

I have one listbox with 5 elements: 
3
cat
dog
4
9

Now I have to check if the selected elements are integers and if they are divisible by 3, if they are I should sum them.thanks
(where for example, 3, dog and 9 are selected and I should get 12 into a label)

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over each element and use `int.TryParse`. If it parses, check `intvalue % 3 == 0` to see if it's divisible by three.

Comment: sorry for multiple edit, just added a code there. Hope you dont mind it.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have the items from your listbox in a list of strings this would be a Linq approach to the problem:

```
List<string> items = new List<string>() { "3", "cat", "dog", "4", "9"};
int sum  = items.Select(x =>
            {
                int intValue;
                return int.TryParse(x, out intValue) ? intValue : 0;
            })
            .Where(x => x % 3 == 0)
            .Sum();
```

Comment: Whoah, that's pretty clever. But if I saw that in our company's codebase I'd fire the guy who wrote it.

Comment: it's pretty straightforward code - can you substantiate what you think "is wrong with it" ?

Comment: A ternary inside an anonymous method, for starters. It's logically straightforward but unmaintainable and difficult to debug from an engineering perspective.